# Is it possible to avoid downloading a pdf file on website when viewing it?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

When I click a link to pdf file on sites, it cannot help download it sometimes.(On FireFox)

I just want to view it.

So, I'm thinking of making web extension which enables to avoid downloading when viewing it.

Is it possible?

Comment: There should be existing extensions for that, they set `Content-Disposition` to inline or something.

Comment: Thanks,@wOxxOm. I can set that extensions and solve.

Comment: Thanks,@KJ.I understand the outline of process of making pdf.